# How to add starting limit and ending limit in loopback

Tags: javascript, loopbackjs

I am trying to fetch some data from a MySQL database based on some condition with limit keyword in Loopback.io, but I am only able to use `limit` with one value. Basically I need to replicate the query
 `SELECT * FROM ace_new.customer_profile limit 10,5` 
using Loopback. I tried this:

```
weapons.find({
  order: 'id DESC',
  limit: 5,
});
```

In this I need to take 5 rows after 10 row; how can I do that and put 2 values in the limit in Loopback?

Comment: Will this link help - [Working with Pagination and LoopBack](https://strongloop.com/strongblog/working-with-pagination-and-loopback/) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the skip filter.

```
weapons.find({
  order: 'id DESC',
  skip: 10,
  limit: 5,
});
```

https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Skip-filter.html